# Remove all Div wrapper from comment form

Tags: 7, forms, theming, comments

I want to strip all default Drupal form wrappers and have something like below in comment form output

```
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                        <input type="text" name="website" placeholder="Website">
                        <textarea name="comment_body" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
                        <input type="submit" value="Send">
                    </form>
```

I try

```
    $form['comment_body']['#theme_wrappers'] = array();
    $form['subject']['#theme_wrappers'] = array();
    $form['author']['mail']['#theme_wrappers'] = array();
    $form['author']['name']['#theme_wrappers'] = array();
```

But not worked for `comment_body` field, 
I also use `Display Suit` I want to know how Can implement comment form like I want without any wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you need to create one template page for comment-form.tpl.php. For this you need to specify in template.php that uses template page.

```
<?php
function phptemplate_comment_form($form) {
  return _phptemplate_callback('comment-form', array('form' => $form));
}
?>
```

and in comment-form.tpl.php you can create your own strcution like

```
print drupal_render($form['name']);
print drupal_render($form['comment_body']);
print drupal_render($form['subject']);
print drupal_render($form['author']['mail']);
print drupal_render($form['author']['name']);
```

This works for me with register/login form.

Comment: but when you  use `drupal_render`  all div wrapper will be rendered !!!!